# mootools store variable in the parent from iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, mootools

I use milkbox to display an overlay window, the overlay is an iframe basically.

I have some js code that runs in the iframe and on body.unload event i want to store something in the parent document.

Picture it like this

```
->  overlay is open:
     bla...
     bla...

     function store() { window.parent.document.store('myVar',var);}
     document.body.onunload = store;

<- overlay got closed
   onClose event gets triggered
   var myVar = document.retrieve('myVar');
```

at this point i should have that var i stored from iframe. Problem is that only IE doesn't want to retrieve this. I tried window.parent.myVar = myVar, it doesn't get recognized when the onClose event gets triggered...

I tried storing it in the window, nothing...it's like whatever happens in the iframe is separate... This is NOT CROSSDOMAIN! so why does this happen?

I tried chrome and firefox, both work as they should. Only the crazy IE doesn't want to allow me to store in retrieve stuff.

Please help!!

Comment: is the iframe from the same domain? if not you will not be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If they are from the same domain and we can rule out security as the issue this will work:

both parent and iframe will have to include mooTools

Parent Window

```
// Within your onClose handler:

 var myVar = $(document).retrieve('myVar'));
 alert(myVar);
```

Iframe:

```
 var store = function() {
        $(window.parent.document).store('myVar','123');
    }

 window.addEvent("beforeunload", store);
```

Tested in IE7 IE8 FF11 worked!